# Parenting/Joining a helmet to a skeleton rig

Tags: modeling, rigging, parent

I'm looking for help on how to parent/join this helmet:

[image]

With this skeleton rig:

[image]

Sorry if it's super simple I just can't seem to figure it out for the life of me. I feel like it's obvious but whatever I try it doesn't parent with the rig when I try to animate.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The helmet consists of 2 elements msh_vents_topSide and msh_visor. You need to select both of them with SHIFT+click, then still with Shift select bone "head" (it's top most circle in "rig" rig), then press CTRL+P and choose Bone. This way whole helmet will be parented to head bone with weight 1 and no need for weight painting.

Answer (score 1):

It should parent the same way as any other objects, but you'll have to go into "weight-painting mode" on the helmet with either your head or neck bone selected and paint the entire helmet. I'm relatively new to blender myself, but I just had to do this for a character's hat. Just make sure you only have it painted on one bone or the other, not both. Hope that helps!